# Could not Right Click on taskbar icons and start menu could not open in windows 10

Tags: audio, windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I installed windows 10 two days ago. First day, it worked fine, but now, when I right click on taskbar icons, or try to open start menu, or left click on Volume, Network or Time icon on right side of taskbar, it does nothing. 
I have tried many things like:
Restarting my PC.
Restarting my taskbar.
Scanning my PC.

Please give me some suggestions or i am comming back to windows 8 :p

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a little bit and it could be that one of your previously installed Shell-Extensions cause Problems here. You could try the following:

1. Download and install [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). (You should select the free version)
2. When you finished installing, open CCleaner and go to Tools > Startup > Context Menu.
3. Deactivate all Items by selecting everything ([Ctrl] + A) and clicking the "Disable"-Button on the right.
4. Reactivate the the Items **one by one** and after each reactivated entry, try testing if the rightclick is working again.

I once had the same problem and this method worked perfectly fine. I just left the causing entry deactivated. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you got around that Problem by now... If I'm honest: I didn't really look at the Date :/